# Wireless unable to work ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: wireless

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS alongside my windows 8.1 on a Dell Inspiron 5520. The problem is that there is no wireless setting on anything showing up and I don't always the LAN available. The wireless works flawless on windows but there is no sign of it on Ubuntu. Any help to fix this issue would help a lot.
Regards.

Comment: Usually a matter of the wireless card not being recognized. What brand is it?

Comment: It is a Dell Wireless 1704 802.11b/g/n

Comment: Can you give the result of the command lspci?

Comment: I don't know how to. I am new to ubuntu so it would be quite helpful if you tell me how to do that.

Comment: On your keyboard press these keys at the same time: ctrl, alt and t then you get a window with a black background which is the terminal. Now type lspci and press the enter key.

Comment: Done. What next.

Comment: Add the result of the command lspci to your question above please, so edit the question.

Comment: Well the network controller is - network controller : broadcom corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)

Comment: And sorry I can't edit and add all that as I am discussing this right now from my phone. My ubuntu has no internet access.

Comment: No worries. You've giving the information that I needed which is the exact brand of your card. The problem you're talking about is a known problem and can be solved. I'm preparing an answer to your question, so hang on...

Answer (score 1):

Go to the terminal (see my comments on your question above). In the terminal type:
`sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`.
You're asked for a password. This is the same one as you use to log in. The computer starts doing a series of actions now and shows a lot of text. If it finishes then you type:
`sudo modprobe wl`
Now you should see wireless networks. If not then restart your computer and you'll certainly see wireless networks. Yesterday I've done this on a computer of a friend of mine so I'm sure this will work.

Comment: Man, you are a genius. It worked perfectly

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. If you're satisfied with my answer then please accept it by clicking on the checkmark in the left margin next to my answer and upvote it also.  This will earn me additional reputation on this site.